# When converting pb to tflite using toco, toco has succeeded, but no result

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I tried to convert my pb file to tflite.
toco has shown success
I have no results.

use code

```
bazel run tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- \
--input_file=opt_mask_rcnn_New.pb \
--output_file=tmp/opt_mask_rcnn_New.tflite \
--input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3:1,93:1,1,4 \
--input_arrays=input_image,input_image_meta,input_anchors\
--output_arrays=output_detections,output_mrcnn_class,output_mrcnn_bbox,output_mrcnn_mask,output_rois,output_rpn_class,output_rpn_bbox \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--inference_input_type=FLOAT
```

toco print in console

```
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.294s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco '--input_file=opt_mask_rcnn_New.pb' '--output_file=tmp/opt_mask_rcnn_New.tflite' '--input_shape=1,,,3:1,93:1,1,4' '--input_arrays=input_image,input_image_meta,input_anchors--output_arrays=output_detections,output_mrcnn_class,output_mrcnn_bbox,output_mrcnn_mask,output_rois,output_rpn_class,output_rpn_bbox' '--inference_type=FLOAT' 
'--oINFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

But my tmp folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here

```
--output_file=tmp/opt_mask_rcnn_New.tflite \
```

Try

```
--output_file=/tmp/opt_mask_rcnn_New.tflite \
```

Or some another absolute path